# Generating ssl certs for mysql trouble

Tags: mysql, openssl

I'm following the instructions from here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-ssl-certs.html

But at the end of it, I get the following

```
[root@thor newcert]# openssl verify -CAfile ca-cert.pem server-cert.pem client-cert.pem
server-cert.pem: /C=GB/ST=Berkshire/L=Newbury/O=My Company Ltd
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
client-cert.pem: /C=GB/ST=Berkshire/L=Newbury/O=My Company Ltd
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

How can I go about debugging this?  I'm a bit confused, since following these instructions worked a couple days ago, and I can't get it to work again.  I've tried this as both a user account and root.

Thank you.

-Nick

Edit: Using CentOS 5.7 and MySQL 5.5.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing.  I think the errors were because I created the key myself.  I don't know why I wasn't getting the errors before.

I thought the errors were a problem because mysql could not read my certs.  It turns out SELinux was preventing mysql from reading the certs.  I used this to figure out SELinux http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux, and in the end, just moved to certs into a sub directory of /var/lib/mysql